# Problemas validando formulario bootstrap

Tags: jquery, formularios, bootstrap-4

He estado trabajando en un formulario con bootstrap. Lamentablemente tengo problemas con la validación en jquery. El formulario no se valida y no se comprime como debiera si los campos están llenos. Agregué console log para saber que estoy recibiendo pero la consola no indica nada. Gracias de antemano.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formFields").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var formVa = $("input[type=radio][name='FormED[]']:checked").length;
        var formVb = $("input[type=radio][name='FormEH[]']:checked").length;
        var formVc = $("input[type=radio][name='FormET[]']:checked").length;
        var formVd = $("input[type=radio][name='FormED[]']:checked").length;
        var FvNombre = $("input[type=text][name=FormN]").val();
        var FvMail = $("input[type=email][name=FormM]").val();
        
        valid = false;
        
        ////////////////////////////////////  LIMPIAR FORMULARIO...  ////////////////////////////////////
        $('#FP').removeClass("is-invalid");
        $('#FN').removeClass("is-invalid");
        $('#FM').removeClass("is-invalid");


        /////////////////////////////////  VALIDAR FORMULARIO...  ///////////////////////////////
        if (formVa === 0) {
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(0).html("POR FAVOR CONTESTA LA PREGUNTA !<br/>");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(0).css({"padding-top" : "0.4rem" , "padding-bottom" : "1.8rem" , "color" : "#dc3545" , "font-size" : "12px"});
            $(".Fpreliminar").find("p").eq(1).css("color", "#dc3545");
            valid = false;       
        } else{
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(0).html("");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(0).css("padding-top", "0rem");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find("p").eq(1).css("color", "#555");
        }
        if (formVb === 0) {
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(1).html("POR FAVOR CONTESTA LA PREGUNTA !<br/>");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(1).css({"padding-top" : "0.4rem" , "padding-bottom" : "0.8rem" , "color" : "#dc3545" , "font-size" : "12px"});
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".col-12").eq(5).removeClass("mt-3");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find("p").eq(2).css("color", "#dc3545");
            valid = false;       
        } else {
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(1).html("");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(1).css("padding-top", "0rem");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".col-12").eq(5).addClass("mt-3");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find("p").eq(2).css("color", "#555");
        }
        if (formVc === 0) {
            $(".Fsegundo").find(".invalid").eq(0).html("POR FAVOR CONTESTA LA PREGUNTA !<br/>");
            $(".Fsegundo").find(".invalid").eq(0).css({"padding-top" : "1rem" , "color" : "#dc3545" , "font-size" : "12px"});
            $(".Fsegundo").find("p").eq(1).css("color", "#dc3545");
            valid = false;       
        } else{
            $(".Fsegundo").find(".invalid").eq(0).html("");
            $(".Fsegundo").find(".invalid").eq(0).css("padding-top", "0rem");
            $(".Fsegundo").find("p").eq(1).css("color", "#555");
        }
        if (formVd === 0) {
            $(".Ftercero").find(".invalid").eq(0).html("POR FAVOR CONTESTA LA PREGUNTA !<br/>");
            $(".Ftercero").find(".invalid").eq(0).css({"padding-top" : "1rem" , "color" : "#dc3545" , "font-size" : "12px"});
            $(".Ftercero").find("p").eq(1).css("color", "#dc3545");
            valid = false;       
        } else{
            $(".Ftercero").find(".invalid").eq(0).html("");
            $(".Ftercero").find(".invalid").eq(0).css("padding-top", "0rem");
            $(".Ftercero").find("p").eq(1).css("color", "#555");
        }
        if ((FvNombre).length < 2) {
            $("#FN").addClass("is-invalid");
            valid = false;
        } 
        if (FvMail.indexOf('@', 0) == -1 || FvMail.indexOf('.', 0) == -1) {
            $("#FM").addClass("is-invalid");
            valid = false;  
        } 
        
         /////////////////////////////////  SI SE ENVÍA CON ÉXITO...
         if(valid){
            $('#multiCollapseExample1 [data-toggle=collapse]').prop('disabled',false);
            $("#formFields").trigger("reset");
            $('#btn').trigger('click');
            console.log("es válido");
        }
        
        /////////////////////////////////  SI NO...
        if (valid = false) {
            $('#multiCollapseExample1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
                $('#multiCollapseExample1 [data-toggle=collapse]').prop('disabled',true);
            });
            console.log("no es válido");
        }
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row justify-content-around mr-3 ml-3">
   <div class="col-6">
    <button class="btn principal btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block mt-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1" id="btn">FORMULARIO</button>
    <form name="form" id="formFields" method="" action="" enctype="">
     <div class="form-group collapse px-3" id="multiCollapseExample1">    
      <div class="row Fpreliminar">
       <div class="col-12 text-center mt-3"> 
        <p class="h5"><strong> 1  SECCIÓN:</strong></p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-12 my-3">
        <label>Pregunta formulario</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="">
       </div>
       <fieldset>
        <div class="col-12"> 
         <p class="h6"><em>Pregunta formulario</em></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormED[]" id="" value="si">
          <label>Sí</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormED[]" id="" value="no">
          <label>No</label>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="invalid"></div>
        </div>
       </fieldset>       
       <fieldset>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"> 
         <p class="h6"><em>Pregunta formulario</em></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormEH[]" id="" value="si">
          <label>Sí</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormEH[]" id="" value="no">
          <label>No</label>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="invalid"></div>
        </div>
       </fieldset>
       <div class="col-12 mt-3">
        <p class="h6 pb-1"><em>Pregunta formulario</em></p>
        <input type="text" name="FormEP" id="FP" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12 my-3"></div>
      </div> 
      <div class="row Fsegundo">
       <div class="col-12"> 
        <p class="h5 text-center"><strong> 2 SECCIÓN:</strong></p>
       </div>
       <fieldset>
        <div class="col-12 mb-3"> 
         <p class="h5 mt-2"><em>Elije una opción:</em></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div>
           <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormET[]" id="" value="">
           </div>
          </div>
          <div>
           <p class="text-justify my-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun</p>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div>
           <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormET[]" id="" value="">
           </div>
          </div>
          <div>
           <p class="text-justify my-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun</p>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="invalid"></div>
        </div>
       </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12 my-3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row Ftercero">
       <div class="col-12"> 
        <p class="h5 text-center"><strong> 3  SECCIÓN:</strong></p>
       </div>
       <fieldset>
        <div class="col-12 mb-3"> 
         <p class="h5 mt-2"><em>Elije una opción:</em></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div>
           <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormED[]" id="" value="">
           </div>
          </div>
          <div>
           <p class="text-justify my-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun</p>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div>
           <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormED[]" id="" value="">
           </div>
          </div>
          <div>
           <p class="text-justify my-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun</p>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="invalid"></div>
        </div>
       </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12 my-3"></div>
      </div>                        
      <div class="row Fdatos">
       <div class="col-12"> 
        <p class="h5 text-center"><strong> 4  SECCIÓN:</strong></p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-12 my-3">
        <input type="text" name="FormN" id="FN" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Nombre">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">POR FAVOR INGRESA TU NOMBRE !</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-12">
        <input type="email" name="FormM" id="FM" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Email">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">POR FAVOR INGRESA UN CORREO !</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-12 my-3">
        <input type="tel" name="FormET" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Teléfono">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12 my-3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
       <div class="col-8">
        <input type="submit" name="enviarForm" id="enviar" class="form-control btn btn-secondary my-1 mb-4" value="SUBMIT" />
       </div>
      </div>   
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-zDnhMsjVZfS3hiP7oCBRmfjkQC4fzxVxFhBx8Hkz2aZX8gEvA/jsP3eXRCvzTofP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas inicializar la variable `valid` en `true`.  Ademas te faltaba un signo `=` en la comparacion.  Quedaria asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formFields").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var formVa = $("input[type=radio][name='FormED[]']:checked").length;
        var formVb = $("input[type=radio][name='FormEH[]']:checked").length;
        var formVc = $("input[type=radio][name='FormET[]']:checked").length;
        var formVd = $("input[type=radio][name='FormED[]']:checked").length;
        var FvNombre = $("input[type=text][name=FormN]").val();
        var FvMail = $("input[type=email][name=FormM]").val();
        
        valid = true;
        
        ////////////////////////////////////  LIMPIAR FORMULARIO...  ////////////////////////////////////
        $('#FP').removeClass("is-invalid");
        $('#FN').removeClass("is-invalid");
        $('#FM').removeClass("is-invalid");


        /////////////////////////////////  VALIDAR FORMULARIO...  ///////////////////////////////
        if (formVa === 0) {
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(0).html("POR FAVOR CONTESTA LA PREGUNTA !<br/>");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(0).css({"padding-top" : "0.4rem" , "padding-bottom" : "1.8rem" , "color" : "#dc3545" , "font-size" : "12px"});
            $(".Fpreliminar").find("p").eq(1).css("color", "#dc3545");
            valid = false;       
        } else{
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(0).html("");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(0).css("padding-top", "0rem");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find("p").eq(1).css("color", "#555");
        }
        if (formVb === 0) {
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(1).html("POR FAVOR CONTESTA LA PREGUNTA !<br/>");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(1).css({"padding-top" : "0.4rem" , "padding-bottom" : "0.8rem" , "color" : "#dc3545" , "font-size" : "12px"});
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".col-12").eq(5).removeClass("mt-3");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find("p").eq(2).css("color", "#dc3545");
            valid = false;       
        } else {
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(1).html("");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".invalid").eq(1).css("padding-top", "0rem");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find(".col-12").eq(5).addClass("mt-3");
            $(".Fpreliminar").find("p").eq(2).css("color", "#555");
        }
        if (formVc === 0) {
            $(".Fsegundo").find(".invalid").eq(0).html("POR FAVOR CONTESTA LA PREGUNTA !<br/>");
            $(".Fsegundo").find(".invalid").eq(0).css({"padding-top" : "1rem" , "color" : "#dc3545" , "font-size" : "12px"});
            $(".Fsegundo").find("p").eq(1).css("color", "#dc3545");
            valid = false;       
        } else{
            $(".Fsegundo").find(".invalid").eq(0).html("");
            $(".Fsegundo").find(".invalid").eq(0).css("padding-top", "0rem");
            $(".Fsegundo").find("p").eq(1).css("color", "#555");
        }
        if (formVd === 0) {
            $(".Ftercero").find(".invalid").eq(0).html("POR FAVOR CONTESTA LA PREGUNTA !<br/>");
            $(".Ftercero").find(".invalid").eq(0).css({"padding-top" : "1rem" , "color" : "#dc3545" , "font-size" : "12px"});
            $(".Ftercero").find("p").eq(1).css("color", "#dc3545");
            valid = false;       
        } else{
            $(".Ftercero").find(".invalid").eq(0).html("");
            $(".Ftercero").find(".invalid").eq(0).css("padding-top", "0rem");
            $(".Ftercero").find("p").eq(1).css("color", "#555");
        }
        if ((FvNombre).length < 2) {
            $("#FN").addClass("is-invalid");
            valid = false;
        } 
        if (FvMail.indexOf('@', 0) == -1 || FvMail.indexOf('.', 0) == -1) {
            $("#FM").addClass("is-invalid");
            valid = false;  
        } 
        
         /////////////////////////////////  SI SE ENVÍA CON ÉXITO...
         if(valid){
            $('#multiCollapseExample1 [data-toggle=collapse]').prop('disabled',false);
            $("#formFields").trigger("reset");
            $('#btn').trigger('click');
            console.log("es válido");
        }
        
        /////////////////////////////////  SI NO...
        if (valid == false) {
            $('#multiCollapseExample1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
                $('#multiCollapseExample1 [data-toggle=collapse]').prop('disabled',true);
            });
            console.log("no es válido");
        }
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row justify-content-around mr-3 ml-3">
   <div class="col-6">
    <button class="btn principal btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block mt-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1" id="btn">FORMULARIO</button>
    <form name="form" id="formFields" method="" action="" enctype="">
     <div class="form-group collapse px-3" id="multiCollapseExample1">    
      <div class="row Fpreliminar">
       <div class="col-12 text-center mt-3"> 
        <p class="h5"><strong> 1  SECCIÓN:</strong></p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-12 my-3">
        <label>Pregunta formulario</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="">
       </div>
       <fieldset>
        <div class="col-12"> 
         <p class="h6"><em>Pregunta formulario</em></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormED[]" id="" value="si">
          <label>Sí</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormED[]" id="" value="no">
          <label>No</label>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="invalid"></div>
        </div>
       </fieldset>       
       <fieldset>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"> 
         <p class="h6"><em>Pregunta formulario</em></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormEH[]" id="" value="si">
          <label>Sí</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormEH[]" id="" value="no">
          <label>No</label>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="invalid"></div>
        </div>
       </fieldset>
       <div class="col-12 mt-3">
        <p class="h6 pb-1"><em>Pregunta formulario</em></p>
        <input type="text" name="FormEP" id="FP" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12 my-3"></div>
      </div> 
      <div class="row Fsegundo">
       <div class="col-12"> 
        <p class="h5 text-center"><strong> 2 SECCIÓN:</strong></p>
       </div>
       <fieldset>
        <div class="col-12 mb-3"> 
         <p class="h5 mt-2"><em>Elije una opción:</em></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div>
           <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormET[]" id="" value="">
           </div>
          </div>
          <div>
           <p class="text-justify my-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun</p>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div>
           <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormET[]" id="" value="">
           </div>
          </div>
          <div>
           <p class="text-justify my-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun</p>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="invalid"></div>
        </div>
       </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12 my-3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row Ftercero">
       <div class="col-12"> 
        <p class="h5 text-center"><strong> 3  SECCIÓN:</strong></p>
       </div>
       <fieldset>
        <div class="col-12 mb-3"> 
         <p class="h5 mt-2"><em>Elije una opción:</em></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div>
           <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormED[]" id="" value="">
           </div>
          </div>
          <div>
           <p class="text-justify my-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun</p>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div>
           <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="FormED[]" id="" value="">
           </div>
          </div>
          <div>
           <p class="text-justify my-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun</p>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
         <div class="invalid"></div>
        </div>
       </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12 my-3"></div>
      </div>                        
      <div class="row Fdatos">
       <div class="col-12"> 
        <p class="h5 text-center"><strong> 4  SECCIÓN:</strong></p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-12 my-3">
        <input type="text" name="FormN" id="FN" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Nombre">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">POR FAVOR INGRESA TU NOMBRE !</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-12">
        <input type="email" name="FormM" id="FM" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Email">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">POR FAVOR INGRESA UN CORREO !</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-12 my-3">
        <input type="tel" name="FormET" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Teléfono">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12 my-3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
       <div class="col-8">
        <input type="submit" name="enviarForm" id="enviar" class="form-control btn btn-secondary my-1 mb-4" value="SUBMIT" />
       </div>
      </div>   
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-zDnhMsjVZfS3hiP7oCBRmfjkQC4fzxVxFhBx8Hkz2aZX8gEvA/jsP3eXRCvzTofP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias @alanfcm, no me había fijado...